# Async await function with exec over SSH

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I want to run several functions in a row on a server over SSH, one after another. I can use await/async functions for this, but can't get this example to work: Log some text, run `uptime` (wait to finish), log more text.

**I should see output:**

```html
Before await function
STDOUT: (all the uptime info here)
Uptime completed successfully.
After await function
```

**But right now I see:**

```html
Before await function
After await function
STDOUT: (all the uptime info here)
Uptime completed successfully.
```

The function `mainFunction` should not print both console logs before the function is finished.

**Here is my example:**

```js
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;

const conn = new Client();

function uptimeFunction() {
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;

      stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
        conn.end();

        if (code === 0) {
          console.log('Uptime completed successfully.');
        }
      }).on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
      }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
      });
    });
  });

  conn.connect(staging);
};

function awaitFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(uptimeFunction());
  });
}

async function mainFunction() {
  console.log('Before await function');

  await awaitFunction();

  console.log('After await function');
}

mainFunction();
```

I have looked into "ssh2-promise" but I did not understand the example for "exec" that would help. If I really do need to use ssh2-promise, how would that look for this example?

Am I doing something wrong, or `await` doesn't work as I thought over SSH?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like in `awaitFunction` you immediately just resolve the promise with the return value of `uptimeFunction`, which is not asynchronous.

Comment: Got it. Also, I updated my question to remove async from `awaitFunction` as not needed. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `awaitFunction` resolves instantly and isn't tied to the ssh stuff.

Let's take a closer look:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(uptimeFunction());
});
```

This promise will resolve as soon as `uptimeFunction` finishes executing. When does that happen? It happens when `conn.on('ready', function() {` finishes executing. Unfortunately, it is but an event binding. It does not actually wait for the anything, thereby letting the promise resolve.

To address this, you need to pass your resolution function further down.

```js
function uptimeFunction(resolve, reject) {
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;

      stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
        conn.end();

        if (code === 0) {
          console.log('Uptime completed successfully.');
          // Success! Resolve.
          resolve();
        } else {
          // Something went wrong, reject promise!
          reject();
        }
      }).on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
      }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
      });
    });
  });

  conn.connect(staging);
};


async function awaitFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    uptimeFunction(resolve, reject);
  });
}
```

Comment: I would expect to see the the `uptimeFunction` return a promise.  i.e.: begins with `return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { ...` rather than split the pattern up across functions.  But if you must, then at least acknowledge that `uptimeFunction` already accepts arguments `(resolve, reject)` so you can say `return new Promise(uptimeFunction)`. and `awaitFunction` does not need to be declared `async`.

Comment: @Wyck The confusion of OP is concerning how callbacks and promises interact. I wanted to minimize the diff between OP and my answer for clarity. The `reject` is also intentional, as an error output is an exceptional state.

Comment: Unlikely that you want to resolve immediately upon receiving data.  data is streamed and must be accumulated.  resolve likely wants to happen on close, conditionally upon also having accumulated a valid payload of data.

Comment: You are correct, I missed the `close` event. Updated the answer.

Comment: This is working! Thanks I'm just learning Promise and appreciate the explanation.